# How do I disable drag and drop on NSTextView?

Tags: drag-and-drop, nstextview, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I have a `NSWindowController` that contains several `NSViewControllers`. I would like to universally accept drag and drop events with the NSWindowController class and not be intercepted by other views such as `NSTextView` (contained in a `NSViewController`)

How can I tell `NSTextView` to ignore the drag & drop event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that there were two things needed to skip past `NSTextView`'s interception of the drag and drop event.

In the `NSViewController` containing your `NSTextView`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self noDragInView:self.view];
}

- (void)noDragInView:(NSView *)view
{
    for (NSView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        [subview unregisterDraggedTypes];
        if (subview.subviews.count) [self noDragInView:subview];
    }
}
```

Now subclass your `NSTextView` and add this method:

```
- (NSArray *)acceptableDragTypes
{
    return nil;
}
```

The `NSTextView` should now properly ignore the drag and drop event and leave it to be handled by the NSWindow.

Comment: I think it is enough to just implement acceptableDragTypes inside of subclass.

Answer (score 6):

It is sufficient to subclass the NSTextView and override the getter for its `acceptableDragTypes` property, no need to `unregisterDraggedTypes`. In Swift:

```
override var acceptableDragTypes : [String] {
    return [String]()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
import Cocoa

class NSTextViewNoDrop: NSTextView {

    override var acceptableDragTypes: [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType] { return [] }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight update.

```
import Cocoa

class MyTextView : NSTextView {
    // don't accept any drag types into the text view
    override var acceptableDragTypes : [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType] {
        return [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType]()
    }
}
```