# Prevent that text deselection requires double-click in NSTextView

Tags: swift, nstextview

I have got a simple NSTextView inside a NSPopover. Most often selection and text editing works as suggested; i.e. i-beam cursor and current selection deselects when I click somewhere else inside the selection.

However, sometimes when the NSPopover is toggled the cursor is replaced with a pointer cursor and the selection won't disappear on click. While in this state the text is also draggable.

I want my NSTextView to behave just like in TextEdit and similar apps; the selection should never be draggable and should deselect on a single click. The cursor should also stay as i-beam.

How can I accomplish this behavior?

[current and expected behavior, illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8KCP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable drag and drop on NSTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482596/how-do-i-disable-drag-and-drop-on-nstextview)